# Django best practice for project setup

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project that will have some functionality such as logging in, registering, sending messages to other users, or creating events.

From what I understand about Django, I would separate all of those features into their own apps such as accounts app (which would have registering), messaging app, and an events app.

If I am correct so far, where would the code go that combines all of those apps that makes up my project? Would it be another app? And what would be the name of said app? (According to best practice)

Thanks!

Comment: I usually just have another app that has a name similar to the project name that ties everything together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "If I am correct so far, where would the code go that combines all of
>   those apps that makes up my project? Would it be another app? And what
>   would be the name of said app? (According to best practice)"

You are correct so far. Keep in mind that for some features there are already existing apps you can just "plug into" your project, like for [registration](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/registration/), or built-in to Django, like [logging in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

I don't think there is a best practice for naming the app which fuses all together. Just go with what you think is an appropriate name. I usually simply name it `web`.

Comment: thank you. that helps a lot as well! another quick question -- would my models in my "web" app simply inherit from the models in accounts for instance? assuming i wanted to change the accounts functionality a bit?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "accounts". If you just mean user data you can simply use the user profile: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users. If you really mean extending functionality you should have a look into extending django.contrib.auth which usually means inherit from django's user model and writing your own custom authentification backend: http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/ as an example.

Comment: edited my comment again to give you some more info. Hope that helps.

Comment: that's good stuff. it seems it's a bit outdated, does it still hold true?

Comment: Generally yes. The keyword here is "custom authentification backend". The actual implementation might have changed slightly over the years, but the idea is still the same. There are lots of question regarding this in stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 1):

The basic Django setup will look like this when you run command

`django-admin.py startproject foo`

```
foo/
    manage.py
    foo/
       __init__.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
```

It's fine but recommended way for project setup is different. The recommended structure is like creating different modules as individual application and then connect it from root. Please refer [this](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/) link for brief understanding of project layout.